# how do i create a filter of planned size from a population?

Tags: anylogic

i'd like to create a list with planned size.Following this example,i do not want  all the women of "people" population,but only (for example) 50.Suggestions?Thanks for the help

List women = filter( people, p -> p.gender == FEMALE );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be something like this

List  women = filter(people,p -> p.gender == FEMALE ).subList(0,50);

be careful that the number 50, you need to be sure that you actually have 50 possible women, otherwise you will get error.